# Spring boot http requests open threads that never close

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, out-of-memory, undertow

I am trying to do some performance testing of my boot app prior to releasing it, so I am running some test to see memory usage, thread count etc.  I am noticing that as I make http requests to the endpoints of the app (including the actuate endpoints) I see "XNIO-2 task-n" threads get created and never cleaned up.

1. java version = "1.8.0_66"
2. Gradle version = 3.5
3. springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
4. Server = undertow

Neither the Rest controller nor the service open any additional threads.
I have looked at the following: 
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/261 but I am not using the GeoApi.

```
Name: XNIO-2 task-46
State: WAITING on  java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@7155b807
Total blocked: 0  Total waited: 1

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As long as no http requests are made the thread count stays constant, does anyone know of any known issues that would cause this?

Comment: Is that where you have a bottleneck in the application? It's good to measure performance, it is even better to first pinpoint the parts where your application is the slowest to get a better performance increase

Comment: What do you mean by never cleaned up? I do believe it's the perfectly normal behavior of a thread pool with a fixed amount of worker threads. It will create new threads until the max thread count is reached then it will re-use them. This max count is configurable in undertow.